# Filtering Service Paths that are Enclosed within Quotations - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script where I can search for windows service paths and filter those that are enclosed between quotation marks. I have got it to display the services e.g. Name, DisplayName, PathName and StartMode but now I want it to filter all the PathNames that are in between quotations. How do I do it? See my code below:

**PowerShell Script:**

```
gwmi win32_service Name, DisplayName, PathName, StartMode
```

**Intended Result:**

```
c:\windows // without quotations.
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You only want paths that are not enclosed in "", i.e. paths that don't contain a space ?

Comment: I want it to display paths that do contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only output processes with at least one `"` in their `PathName`

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service Name, DisplayName, PathName, StartMode |
    Where-Object PathName -Match "`""
```

Tip : escape character in PS is the **backtick** ` (no that's not a failure of your screen ^^)

Comment: But what if I want it to display those without quotations?

Comment: lol - use `-NotMatch` instead of `-Match`. You could have figured this out by yourself : )

Comment: Apologies lol, I am not very familiar with PowerShell :) thanks

Comment: I know but if you use tab-completion in PS you will get suggestions for switches and such. And never forget to try with your own brain, you will learn better that way.